# Java how to retrieve a particular field form http response

Tags: java, rest, httpresponse

I'm trying to do this by convert the response to json and then find the filed form it.

But I don't know neither how to convert it to json, nor how to traverse the json.

```
@POST
    @Path("/custoemrs")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    Response createCustomer(Customer customer);
```

there would be a id field which I want to extract.

There are too many answers out there, I tried some of them but none is working.

I want to use jackson to process the json file, and I'm using resteasy client.

The response I'm using is javax.ws.rs.core.Response, please kindly base on this to answer

I saw many people said something like

`EntityUtils.toString(entity)`

But I can't even resolve the entityutils...

Comment: Can you please elaborate more how you are getting response & what field you want to extract

Comment: @AshishPatil Thanks for reminder, I have update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjectMapper is the core class in Jackson, use that. There is no need convert anything to a String, Jackson can read directly from the HTTP input stream.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ParseJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream streamFromServer = streamFromServer; //Wherever this comes from
        final JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree( streamFromServer );
        final String yourValue = jsonNode.at( "/path/to/your/value" ).asText();
    }
}
```

Comment: JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(response); I tried this but it told me The method readTree(JsonParser) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (Response). Am I supposed to convert the response as something?

Comment: streamFromServer should be an InputStream, not a Response. There is probably a method in Response to get an InputStream. I don't know the fully-qualified Response class that you're working with so I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not sure how your `Customer` object looks like but below might be helpful to you:

```
String customer = EntityUtils.toString(entity);  // returns your customer in String format.
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  // this is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper class

HashMap<?, ?> map = mapper.readValue(customer, HashMap.class);  

System.out.println(map.get("id")); // extracting id field.
```